# How to integrate twig template engine into PHP MVC architecture with no framework

Tags: php, templates, twig

I am working on a project which is based on MVC architecture (not using any framework) and working fine right now, but the issue is how to integrate twig php template engine. I am posting the layout structure of my project and the code which i am using to load the template and render the view. Please look into and suggest me the right solution to integrate the twig into php mvc architecture,

**Project structure**

- Project1

  - app

    - controllers

      - welcome_controllers.php
    - models
    - views

      - welcome

        - index.html.twig
      - templates

        - layout.html.twig
  - config
  - libraries

    - Twig(twig files resides here)
    - router.php
      **Controller base class**

  class Controller {

  ```
  var $twig = null;

  public function loadTwig() {
      Twig_Autoloader::register();
      $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(
          array (APP_PATH.'/views/')
      );
      // set up environment
      $params = array(
          'cache' => BASE_PATH.'/cache', 
          'auto_reload' => true, // disable cache
          'autoescape' => true
      );
      $this->twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, $params);
  }
  ```

  }

**WelcomeController class**

```
class WelcomeController extends AppController{

    public function index(){
        $this->loadTwig();
        $this->twig->render('welcome/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

**index.html.twig file**

```
{% extends '../templates/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    Index Page Title
{% endblock %}
```

**layout.html.twig file**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       base template text
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, I have defined template layout.html.php in views/templates folder and i want to inherit all the view pages for the controllers from it.
Please someone help me if implemented this thing before or have any idea about this.

Comment: Views in MVC are not just dumb template files. Create a class or function which you can call from your controller which will set up Twig and render the template file. That class/function/set of classes is your view. Does that clear things up? What problem exactly do you have with the integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure If this is what you're asking for, your question is kind of confusing, but maybe telling my own experience will help.

I created my own MVC framework trying to copy some of the best functionalities of Symfony2. I did it by using some of the same vendors, including Twig.

I installed Twig through [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) which automatically generates the autoloader. The way I'm integrating Twig is by creating a `loadTwig` method inside the `__construct` of my main controller:

```
public function loadTwig() {
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(
        array (
            "../html/views",
            "../html/widgets"
        )
    );
    // set up environment
    $params = array(
        'cache' => "../cache", 
        'auto_reload' => true, // disable cache
        'autoescape' => true
    );
    $this->twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, $params);
    // ...
}
```

Then, every time I need to render a template located inside "views" or "widgets" folder I just call:

```
 $this->twig->display('myview.html.twig', array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

The twig loader filesystem loads every template at the same level inside the dirs you define (not sure if it loads the files recursively or just the ones on the root of the dir, you may try this). This means that you don't have to define a path when rendering, extending or including other twig templates. The templates just load and exist at the same level. Try the following:

Filesystem Loader:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(
    // array (APP_PATH.'/views/') you may try if this work, but:
    array (
        APP_PATH.'views/templates',
        APP_PATH.'views/welcome'
        APP_PATH.'views/foo'
        APP_PATH.'views/bar'
    )
);
```

Rendering (use display instead of render):

```
$this->twig->display('index.welcome.html.twig', array('foo' => 'bar')); // if you have more than one index.html.twig, rename your templates :)
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    Index Page Title
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have updated my question for more clearty. I have also tried your code but i am getting error that Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'Looks like you try to load a template outside configured directories.

Comment: Perfect. first of all thank for your support. but now the issue is the file system. I have to add all the view directory into file system as you have mention. Is there any way to automate it, if i create hundred of controllers then the view will contain hundred of folders to the corresponding controllers and adding every controller's view folder into file system would be tedious.

Comment: What about loading the filesystem dynamically for each controller? Something like `$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array(APP_PATH . '/templates/' . $MyController));`

Comment: I have done whatever i have asked till now. I just have another question here. if i have set and get magic method with controller then how would i can get access to those variables which i have set in the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to use Twig to Render data to your templates, take care of passing $twig var to the ___construct of each object class you instantiate and then validate that it's passed okay before render.

**control**

```
$objEmployee = new Employee($objConexion->conectar(), $twig);
```

**class**

```
function __construct($l,$q,$t){

    $this->link     = $l;
    $this->query    = $q;
    $this->twig     = $t;
}
```

**validate twig on class**

```
if (isset($this->twig)){

    all print view and render stuff;

}
```

Then you could easily use your templates on every PHP class instantiated with Twig as a parameter.

Hope this helps.